# Linker script location counter invalid value

Tags: linker, x86-64, ld, osdev, linker-scripts

I am writing a linker script as:

```
  SECTIONS
{
   . = 0x100000;

   .phys . :
   {
       *(.phys.text)
       *(.phys.data)
       . = ALIGN(4K);
   }

   .phys.bss . (NOLOAD) :
   {
       boot_stack_bottom = .;
       . = . + 4K;
       boot_stack_top = .;
       *(.phys.bss)
   }

   . = . + KERNEL_OFFSET;

   .boot . : AT(ADDR(.boot) - KERNEL_OFFSET)
   {
       *(.boot.text)
       *(.boot.data)
   }
}
```

When compiling my code, I expect to have `.phys` section at address `0x100000` which is true. I also expect `.phy.bss` to be at address `0x100000 + SIZEOF(.phys)` but its not. The `.phys.bss` section has address `0x0`. But, if i remove the `.` from the `.phys.bss` section and simply write `.phys.bss (NOLOAD) :` or explicitly specify the address using `0x100000 + SIZEOF(.phys)` everything work OK. Why is `.` invalid for the `.phys.bss` section!?

This is output of the `objdump` for two cases:

- `.phys.bss (NOLOAD) :`

> ```
> architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000112:
> EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
> start address 0x00000000001012b3
>
> Program Header:
>     LOAD off    0x0000000000001000 vaddr 0x0000000000100000 paddr 0x0000000000100000 align 2**12
>          filesz 0x0000000000003000 memsz 0x0000000000006000 flags rw-
>     LOAD off    0x0000000000004000 vaddr 0xffffffff80106000 paddr 0x0000000000106000 align 2**5
>          filesz 0x0000000000008918 memsz 0x000000000060a000 flags rwx
>     LOAD off    0x000000000000d000 vaddr 0xffffffff80710000 paddr 0x0000000000710000 align 2**12
>          filesz 0x0000000000013aa7 memsz 0x0000000000023000 flags rwx
>    STACK off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**4
>          filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000000000 flags rwx
>
> Sections:
> Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
>   0 .phys         00003000  0000000000100000  0000000000100000  00001000  2**12
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
>   1 .phys.bss     00003000  0000000000103000  0000000000103000  00004000  2**12
>                   ALLOC
>   2 .boot         00008918  ffffffff80106000  0000000000106000  00004000  2**5
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, CODE
>   3 .boot.bss     006016e8  ffffffff8010e918  000000000010e918  0000c918  2**5
>                   ALLOC
>   4 .text         00011735  ffffffff80710000  0000000000710000  0000d000  2**4
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
>   5 .rodata       00002372  ffffffff80721735  0000000000721735  0001e735  2**5
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
>   6 .bss          0000e571  ffffffff80723aa7  0000000000723aa7  00020aa7  2**12
>                   ALLOC
>   7 .ehframe      00000fe8  ffffffff80732018  0000000000732018  00020aa7  2**0
>                   ALLOC
> SYMBOL TABLE:
> 0000000000100000 l    d  .phys    0000000000000000 .phys
> 0000000000103000 l    d  .phys.bss    0000000000000000 .phys.bss
> ffffffff80106000 l    d  .boot    0000000000000000 .boot
> ffffffff8010e918 l    d  .boot.bss    0000000000000000 .boot.bss
> ffffffff80710000 l    d  .text    0000000000000000 .text
> ffffffff80721735 l    d  .rodata  0000000000000000 .rodata
> ffffffff80723aa7 l    d  .bss 0000000000000000 .bss
> ffffffff80732018 l    d  .ehframe 0000000000000000 .ehframe
> 0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*    0000000000000000 src/arch/x86/64/head.o
> 000000000010102e l       .phys    0000000000000000 huge_page_error_string
> 0000000000000029 l       *ABS*    0000000000000000 huge_page_error_size
> 00000000001010ff l       .phys    0000000000000000 pcid_error_string
> 0000000000000025 l       *ABS*    0000000000000000 pcid_error_size
> 0000000000101148 l       .phys    0000000000000000 invpcid_error_string
> 0000000000000033 l       *ABS*    0000000000000000 invpcid_error_size
> 000000000010119f l       .phys    0000000000000000 syscall_error_string
> 000000000000003a l       *ABS*    0000000000000000 syscall_error_size
> 0000000000101205 l       .phys    0000000000000000 fsgsbase_error_string
> 0000000000000035 l       *ABS*    0000000000000000 fsgsbase_error_size
> 0000000000102010 l       .phys    0000000000000000 _gdt64_ptr
> 0000000000102020 l       .phys    0000000000000000 _gdt64
> 0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*    0000000000000000 kernel_final.c
> ffffffff80106030 l     F .boot    00000000000000a5 merge_regions
> ffffffff8030f0c0 l     O .boot.bss    0000000000400118 allocated_p_regions
> ffffffff80713930 l     F .text    00000000000000a4 lookupIOPTSlot_resolve_levels
> ffffffff807139e0 l     F .text    00000000000000b9 vtd_process_faults
> ffffffff80713aa0 l     F .text    000000000000005b single_ioapic_init
> ffffffff80723ae0 l     O .bss 0000000000000060 ioredtbl_state
> ffffffff80713b00 l     F .text    000000000000005e lookupPDPTSlot
> ffffffff801060e0 l     F .boot    0000000000000037 init_pat_msr.part.173
> ffffffff80713b60 l     F .text    0000000000000016 Arch_fpuThreadDelete.part.177
> ffffffff80713b80 l     F .text    0000000000000046 preemptionPoint.part.183
> ffffffff80713bd0 l     F .text    0000000000000094 tcbSchedEnqueue.part.186
> ffffffff80713c70 l     F .text    0000000000000094 tcbSchedAppend.part.189
> ffffffff80713d10 l     F .text    0000000000000026 invokeTCB_NotificationControl.part.193
> ffffffff80713d40 l     F .text    000000000000009a parse_bool.constprop.210
> ffffffff80714120 l     F .text    000000000000014e cap_get_capPtr
> ffffffff80714270 l     F .text    000000000000002c cap_get_capMappedASID
> ffffffff80714540 l     F .text    000000000000006d lookup_vtd_context_slot
> ffffffff807146d0 l     F .text    0000000000000071 makeUserPDPTEHugePage
> ffffffff80106d30 l     F .boot    000000000000005e add_mem_p_regs
> ffffffff807150d0 l     F .text    0000000000000076 unmapPDPT
> ffffffff8010e920 l     O .boot.bss    0000000000000018 cpu_identity
> ffffffff80716640 l     F .text    0000000000000088 possibleSwitchTo
> ffffffff807166f0 l     F .text    0000000000000021 scheduleTCB.part.187
> ffffffff80716740 l     F .text    0000000000000012 setThreadState.part.188
> ffffffff80717390 l     F .text    000000000000001a capSwapForDelete.part.184
> ffffffff80723ad0 l     O .bss 0000000000000004 num_ioapics
> ffffffff80723ac8 l     O .bss 0000000000000008 ioapic_target_cpu
> ffffffff8071ce80 l     F .text    0000000000000062 maskInterrupt.part.196
> ffffffff8071d100 l     F .text    0000000000000113 emptySlot.part.197
> ffffffff8071d220 l     F .text    000000000000004a cteDeleteOne.part.198
> ffffffff8071d3b0 l     F .text    000000000000004d handleReply
> ffffffff8071e3a0 l     F .text    00000000000001cc handleRecv
> ffffffff80720b00 l     F .text    00000000000001b4 handleInvocation
> ffffffff80723b40 l     O .bss 0000000000000008 control_reg_order
> ffffffff80712e90 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_d3
> 000000000010117b g     F .phys    000000000000005e syscall_check
> ffffffff80733000 g       .ehframe 0000000000000000 ki_end
> ffffffff80714da0 g     F .text    000000000000001f findMapForASID
> ffffffff8071dc80 g     F .text    00000000000000f0 decodeWriteRegisters
> ffffffff807122c0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_9d
> ffffffff80712fe0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_d9
> ffffffff80713750 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_fb
> ffffffff8010d620 g     F .boot    000000000000012f apic_init
> ffffffff80712b10 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_c3
> ffffffff80715a10 g     F .text    0000000000000011 decodeX86IOSpaceInvocation
> ffffffff80712e20 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_d1
> ffffffff80710f48 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_44
> ffffffff807100ae g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_01
> ffffffff807120c8 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_94
> ffffffff80721520 g     F .text    0000000000000022 c_handle_syscall
> ffffffff80711ca0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_81
> ffffffff807101fe g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_07
> ffffffff80712d08 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_cc
> ffffffff8010cbf0 g     F .boot    00000000000001ba acpi_dmar_scan
> ffffffff807185c0 g     F .text    00000000000007b2 decodeX86ModeMMUInvocation
> ffffffff8010e120 g     F .boot    00000000000001c5 x86_cpuid_initialize
> ffffffff80717130 g     F .text    0000000000000096 cteMove
> ffffffff80724000 g     O .bss 0000000000000010 current_fault
> ffffffff80711f40 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_8d
> ffffffff807103b2 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_0f
> ffffffff80710ab0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_2f
> ffffffff80724010 g     O .bss 0000000000000008 seL4_VMFault_Msg
> ffffffff801061d0 g     F .boot    0000000000000021 apic_send_init_ipi
> ffffffff807184f0 g     F .text    0000000000000082 isFinalCapability
> ffffffff80717870 g     F .text    0000000000000012 isIRQActive
> ffffffff8071e370 g     F .text    0000000000000025 deleteCallerCap
> ffffffff807145b0 g     F .text    0000000000000085 makeUserPDELargePage
> ffffffff807118b0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_6f
> ffffffff80715be0 g     F .text    0000000000000077 Arch_maskCapRights
> ffffffff80719690 g     F .text    00000000000000ae lookupExtraCaps
> ffffffff8010d810 g     F .boot    00000000000000fe tsc_init
> ffffffff8071a030 g     F .text    0000000000000021 performInvocation_Endpoint
> ffffffff807168e0 g     F .text    0000000000000210 decodeX86PortInvocation
> ffffffff80107090 g     F .boot    00000000000031c4 init_vm_state
> ffffffff80710960 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_29
> ffffffff80712aa0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_c1
> ffffffff80713478 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_ee
> ffffffff807190b0 g     F .text    000000000000011c createNewObjects
> ffffffff80711b88 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_7c
> ffffffff807155d0 g     F .text    0000000000000042 switchLocalFpuOwner
> ffffffff80714f20 g     F .text    0000000000000005 Arch_switchToThread
> ffffffff80715a30 g     F .text    00000000000000c5 Arch_deriveCap
> ffffffff80713050 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_db
> ffffffff80713e90 g     F .text    0000000000000030 makeUserPDEPageTable
> ffffffff80711e60 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_89
> ffffffff80710ed8 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_42
> ffffffff8071382a g     F .text    0000000000000035 int_ff
> ffffffff807118e8 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_70
> ffffffff80714d90 g     F .text    0000000000000002 isValidNativeRoot
> ffffffff80710e30 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_3f
> ffffffff80724018 g     O .bss 0000000000000008 seL4_UnknownSyscall_Msg
> ffffffff80719320 g     F .text    0000000000000092 chooseThread
> ffffffff8071ef60 g     F .text    00000000000002d0 invokeTCB_ThreadControl
> ffffffff80725000 g     O .bss 0000000000001000 x64KSGlobalPD
> ffffffff8010b1e0 g     F .boot    00000000000004b1 create_it_address_space
> ffffffff80712b80 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_c5
> ffffffff80711df0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_87
> 0000000000100000 g       *ABS*    0000000000000000 PADDR_LOAD
> ffffffff80716e30 g     F .text    000000000000005f timerTick
> ffffffff80712d40 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_cd
> ffffffff80715350 g     F .text    00000000000000f7 unmapPage
> ffffffff80711098 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_4a
> ffffffff80723a14 g     O .rodata  0000000000000004 gpRegisters
> ffffffff8071d9c0 g     F .text    0000000000000010 invokeTCB_Resume
> ffffffff807132b8 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_e6
> ffffffff80712560 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_a9
> ffffffff80718580 g     F .text    000000000000003d slotCapLongRunningDelete
> ffffffff80726000 g     O .bss 0000000000000008 seL4_CapFault_Msg
> ffffffff80106000 g     F .boot    0000000000000027 _entry_64
> ffffffff80711258 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_52
> ffffffff80711370 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_57
> ffffffff80710458 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_12
> ffffffff80726008 g     O .bss 0000000000000008 x64KSCurrentCR3
> ```

- `.phys.bss . (NOLOAD) :`

> ```
> architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000012:
> EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS
> start address 0x00000000001012b3
>
> Program Header:
>     LOAD off    0x0000000000001000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**12
>          filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000003000 flags rw-
>     LOAD off    0x0000000000000160 vaddr 0xffffffff80003000 paddr 0x0000000000003000 align 2**5
>          filesz 0x0000000000008918 memsz 0x000000000060a000 flags rwx
>     LOAD off    0x0000000000009000 vaddr 0x0000000000100000 paddr 0x0000000000100000 align 2**12
>          filesz 0x0000000000003000 memsz 0x0000000000003000 flags r--
>     LOAD off    0x000000000000c000 vaddr 0xffffffff8060d000 paddr 0x000000000060d000 align 2**12
>          filesz 0x0000000000013aa7 memsz 0x0000000000023000 flags rwx
>    STACK off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**4
>          filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000000000 flags rwx
>
> Sections:
> Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
>   0 .phys         00003000  0000000000100000  0000000000100000  00009000  2**12
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
>   1 .phys.bss     00003000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001000  2**12
>                   ALLOC
>   2 .boot         00008918  ffffffff80003000  0000000000003000  00000160  2**5
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, CODE
>   3 .boot.bss     006016e8  ffffffff8000b918  000000000000b918  00008a78  2**5
>                   ALLOC
>   4 .text         00011735  ffffffff8060d000  000000000060d000  0000c000  2**4
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
>   5 .rodata       00002372  ffffffff8061e735  000000000061e735  0001d735  2**5
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
>   6 .bss          0000e571  ffffffff80620aa7  0000000000620aa7  0001faa7  2**12
>                   ALLOC
>   7 .ehframe      00000fe8  ffffffff8062f018  000000000062f018  0001faa7  2**0
>                   ALLOC
> SYMBOL TABLE:
> 0000000000100000 l    d  .phys    0000000000000000 .phys
> 0000000000000000 l    d  .phys.bss    0000000000000000 .phys.bss
> ffffffff80003000 l    d  .boot    0000000000000000 .boot
> ffffffff8000b918 l    d  .boot.bss    0000000000000000 .boot.bss
> ffffffff8060d000 l    d  .text    0000000000000000 .text
> ffffffff8061e735 l    d  .rodata  0000000000000000 .rodata
> ffffffff80620aa7 l    d  .bss 0000000000000000 .bss
> ffffffff8062f018 l    d  .ehframe 0000000000000000 .ehframe
> 0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*    0000000000000000 src/arch/x86/64/head.o
> 000000000010102e l       .phys    0000000000000000 huge_page_error_string
> 0000000000000029 l       *ABS*    0000000000000000 huge_page_error_size
> 00000000001010ff l       .phys    0000000000000000 pcid_error_string
> 0000000000000025 l       *ABS*    0000000000000000 pcid_error_size
> 0000000000101148 l       .phys    0000000000000000 invpcid_error_string
> 0000000000000033 l       *ABS*    0000000000000000 invpcid_error_size
> 000000000010119f l       .phys    0000000000000000 syscall_error_string
> 000000000000003a l       *ABS*    0000000000000000 syscall_error_size
> 0000000000101205 l       .phys    0000000000000000 fsgsbase_error_string
> 0000000000000035 l       *ABS*    0000000000000000 fsgsbase_error_size
> 0000000000102010 l       .phys    0000000000000000 _gdt64_ptr
> 0000000000102020 l       .phys    0000000000000000 _gdt64
> 0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*    0000000000000000 kernel_final.c
> ffffffff80003030 l     F .boot    00000000000000a5 merge_regions
> ffffffff8020c0c0 l     O .boot.bss    0000000000400118 allocated_p_regions
> ffffffff80610930 l     F .text    00000000000000a4 lookupIOPTSlot_resolve_levels
> ffffffff806109e0 l     F .text    00000000000000b9 vtd_process_faults
> ffffffff80610aa0 l     F .text    000000000000005b single_ioapic_init
> ffffffff80620ae0 l     O .bss 0000000000000060 ioredtbl_state
> ffffffff80610b00 l     F .text    000000000000005e lookupPDPTSlot
> ffffffff800030e0 l     F .boot    0000000000000037 init_pat_msr.part.173
> ffffffff80610b60 l     F .text    0000000000000016 Arch_fpuThreadDelete.part.177
> ffffffff80610b80 l     F .text    0000000000000046 preemptionPoint.part.183
> ffffffff80610bd0 l     F .text    0000000000000094 tcbSchedEnqueue.part.186
> ffffffff80610c70 l     F .text    0000000000000094 tcbSchedAppend.part.189
> ffffffff80610d10 l     F .text    0000000000000026 invokeTCB_NotificationControl.part.193
> ffffffff80610d40 l     F .text    000000000000009a parse_bool.constprop.210
> ffffffff80611120 l     F .text    000000000000014e cap_get_capPtr
> ffffffff80611270 l     F .text    000000000000002c cap_get_capMappedASID
> ffffffff80611540 l     F .text    000000000000006d lookup_vtd_context_slot
> ffffffff806116d0 l     F .text    0000000000000071 makeUserPDPTEHugePage
> ffffffff80003d30 l     F .boot    000000000000005e add_mem_p_regs
> ffffffff806120d0 l     F .text    0000000000000076 unmapPDPT
> ffffffff8000b920 l     O .boot.bss    0000000000000018 cpu_identity
> ffffffff80613640 l     F .text    0000000000000088 possibleSwitchTo
> ffffffff806136f0 l     F .text    0000000000000021 scheduleTCB.part.187
> ffffffff80613740 l     F .text    0000000000000012 setThreadState.part.188
> ffffffff80614390 l     F .text    000000000000001a capSwapForDelete.part.184
> ffffffff80620ad0 l     O .bss 0000000000000004 num_ioapics
> ffffffff80620ac8 l     O .bss 0000000000000008 ioapic_target_cpu
> ffffffff80619e80 l     F .text    0000000000000062 maskInterrupt.part.196
> ffffffff8061a100 l     F .text    0000000000000113 emptySlot.part.197
> ffffffff8061a220 l     F .text    000000000000004a cteDeleteOne.part.198
> ffffffff8061a3b0 l     F .text    000000000000004d handleReply
> ffffffff8061b3a0 l     F .text    00000000000001cc handleRecv
> ffffffff8061db00 l     F .text    00000000000001b4 handleInvocation
> ffffffff80620b40 l     O .bss 0000000000000008 control_reg_order
> ffffffff8060fe90 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_d3
> 000000000010117b g     F .phys    000000000000005e syscall_check
> ffffffff80630000 g       .ehframe 0000000000000000 ki_end
> ffffffff80611da0 g     F .text    000000000000001f findMapForASID
> ffffffff8061ac80 g     F .text    00000000000000f0 decodeWriteRegisters
> ffffffff8060f2c0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_9d
> ffffffff8060ffe0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_d9
> ffffffff80610750 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_fb
> ffffffff8000a620 g     F .boot    000000000000012f apic_init
> ffffffff8060fb10 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_c3
> ffffffff80612a10 g     F .text    0000000000000011 decodeX86IOSpaceInvocation
> ffffffff8060fe20 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_d1
> ffffffff8060df48 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_44
> ffffffff8060d0ae g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_01
> ffffffff8060f0c8 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_94
> ffffffff8061e520 g     F .text    0000000000000022 c_handle_syscall
> ffffffff8060eca0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_81
> ffffffff8060d1fe g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_07
> ffffffff8060fd08 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_cc
> ffffffff80009bf0 g     F .boot    00000000000001ba acpi_dmar_scan
> ffffffff806155c0 g     F .text    00000000000007b2 decodeX86ModeMMUInvocation
> ffffffff8000b120 g     F .boot    00000000000001c5 x86_cpuid_initialize
> ffffffff80614130 g     F .text    0000000000000096 cteMove
> ffffffff80621000 g     O .bss 0000000000000010 current_fault
> ffffffff8060ef40 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_8d
> ffffffff8060d3b2 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_0f
> ffffffff8060dab0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_2f
> ffffffff80621010 g     O .bss 0000000000000008 seL4_VMFault_Msg
> ffffffff800031d0 g     F .boot    0000000000000021 apic_send_init_ipi
> ffffffff806154f0 g     F .text    0000000000000082 isFinalCapability
> ffffffff80614870 g     F .text    0000000000000012 isIRQActive
> ffffffff8061b370 g     F .text    0000000000000025 deleteCallerCap
> ffffffff806115b0 g     F .text    0000000000000085 makeUserPDELargePage
> ffffffff8060e8b0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_6f
> ffffffff80612be0 g     F .text    0000000000000077 Arch_maskCapRights
> ffffffff80616690 g     F .text    00000000000000ae lookupExtraCaps
> ffffffff8000a810 g     F .boot    00000000000000fe tsc_init
> ffffffff80617030 g     F .text    0000000000000021 performInvocation_Endpoint
> ffffffff806138e0 g     F .text    0000000000000210 decodeX86PortInvocation
> ffffffff80004090 g     F .boot    00000000000031c4 init_vm_state
> ffffffff8060d960 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_29
> ffffffff8060faa0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_c1
> ffffffff80610478 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_ee
> ffffffff806160b0 g     F .text    000000000000011c createNewObjects
> ffffffff8060eb88 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_7c
> ffffffff806125d0 g     F .text    0000000000000042 switchLocalFpuOwner
> ffffffff80611f20 g     F .text    0000000000000005 Arch_switchToThread
> ffffffff80612a30 g     F .text    00000000000000c5 Arch_deriveCap
> ffffffff80610050 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_db
> ffffffff80610e90 g     F .text    0000000000000030 makeUserPDEPageTable
> ffffffff8060ee60 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_89
> ffffffff8060ded8 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_42
> ffffffff8061082a g     F .text    0000000000000035 int_ff
> ffffffff8060e8e8 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_70
> ffffffff80611d90 g     F .text    0000000000000002 isValidNativeRoot
> ffffffff8060de30 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_3f
> ffffffff80621018 g     O .bss 0000000000000008 seL4_UnknownSyscall_Msg
> ffffffff80616320 g     F .text    0000000000000092 chooseThread
> ffffffff8061bf60 g     F .text    00000000000002d0 invokeTCB_ThreadControl
> ffffffff80622000 g     O .bss 0000000000001000 x64KSGlobalPD
> ffffffff800081e0 g     F .boot    00000000000004b1 create_it_address_space
> ffffffff8060fb80 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_c5
> ffffffff8060edf0 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_87
> 0000000000100000 g       *ABS*    0000000000000000 PADDR_LOAD
> ffffffff80613e30 g     F .text    000000000000005f timerTick
> ffffffff8060fd40 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_cd
> ffffffff80612350 g     F .text    00000000000000f7 unmapPage
> ffffffff8060e098 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_4a
> ffffffff80620a14 g     O .rodata  0000000000000004 gpRegisters
> ffffffff8061a9c0 g     F .text    0000000000000010 invokeTCB_Resume
> ffffffff806102b8 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_e6
> ffffffff8060f560 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_a9
> ffffffff80615580 g     F .text    000000000000003d slotCapLongRunningDelete
> ffffffff80623000 g     O .bss 0000000000000008 seL4_CapFault_Msg
> ffffffff80003000 g     F .boot    0000000000000027 _entry_64
> ffffffff8060e258 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_52
> ffffffff8060e370 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_57
> ffffffff8060d458 g     F .text    0000000000000038 int_12
> ffffffff80623008 g     O .bss 0000000000000008 x64KSCurrentCR3
> ```

Comment: There is a lack of information. What makes you think `.phys.bss` is being placed at 0x0? Can you show us an OBJDUMP of the linked ELF section header objects for both situations where you use `.phys.bss . (NOLOAD):` and `.phys.bss (NOLOAD)` . You can get all the headers by doing `objdump -x nameofelffile` where nameofelffile is the name of the elf executable.

Comment: What is the target platform. 64-bit ARM or is this intel x86-64. I guess the question might be - what tool chain are you using to build with?

Comment: It is x86-64 and my gcc version is (Debian 5.4.1-2) 5.4.1 20160904

Comment: Is it possible to show the entire output for each objdump you did. I am very curious about the other entries. Something doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: I could not put the whole symbols as stackoverflow does not allow me! hope this (updated with partial symbols) could help!

Comment: Thanks when I get some time a bit later I will look over them. Thanks for making the info available. Someone else may have some ideas as well.

Comment: One other question. Are you creating a 64-bit kernel or a 32-bit kernel?

Comment: I use Debian Jessie stable, don't currently have an environment with Debian Jessie Sid. I'm wondering if there is a bug in the tool chain. Have you tried with a stable release?

Comment: A canonical answer might be found here: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/ld_21.html . The subtle difference between using `.` and not having it will yield a different result depending on the strictest alignment of the input section it is defining.

Comment: Will admit despite the documentation it still seems like a bug that the VMA is reset back to zero with the `.` present especially if the section before it was nonzero in size. Might be an anomaly based on the NOLOAD directive.

Comment: It does not related to NOLOAD because I see same behavior even without the NOLOAD. By the way thank you for you time and helps. This issue is bugging me for long time even if I could use a work around and specify the address explicitly!